# onclick event not working asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

hi frends I have this button and it's button click not working

```
<asp:Button ID="btnfirstnext" runat="server" Text="Next" class="next1 action-button" OnClick="btnfirstnext_Click" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Here, I use JavaScript like

```
$(".next1").click(function () {
            if (animating) return true;
            animating = true;

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();

            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                step: function (now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                    left = (now * 50) + "%";
                    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')' });
                    next_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function () {
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
                //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                easing: 'easeInOutBack'
              // $('btnfirstnext').trigger('click');

            });
        });
```

and I want run some code on button clickevent like

```
protected void btnfirstnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblmessage.text="Hello this button click working";

    }
```

Here you can see this above detail when I load this code it run only JavaScript but not working button click event. and this JavaScript is for one popup. Please help me for out of this.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `OnClientClick="return false;"` part in the aspx. I suspect it's preventing the postback.

Comment: if i remove OnClientClick="return false;" than my page will be load and don't want it because it open one popup when i click on button .

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `false` from `OnClientClick`, if you return false from the `OnClientClick` javascript event handler then you wont get the post back you can return true alway if you always need postback. You can return true or false conditionally otherwise.

Use only jQuery `click` event handler you have and remove On `OnClientClick`

Comment: if i remove OnClientClick="return false;" than my page will be load and don't want it because it open one popup when i click on button .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".next1").click(function () {

   //Your Code here


  });
});
```

And remove it: `OnClientClick="return false;"`

Comment: if i remove OnClientClick="return false;" than my page will be load and don't want it because it open one popup when i click on button .

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `OnClientClick="return false;"` in your `asp:Button`. It is preventing your postback. Your button will need to look something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnfirstnext" runat="server" Text="Next" class="next1 action-button" OnClick="btnfirstnext_Click" />
```

I will only make use of the `click` event handler to handle this. I would also add the `document ready` part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".next1").click(function() {
          // Add the rest of your code
     });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnfirstnext" runat="server" Text="Next" class="next1 action-button" OnClick="btnfirstnext_Click"; />
```

You have to remove OnClientClick="return false;".